# angularjs ng-repeat ordering string arrays in numerical order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of post with ids like
`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12`
(json format)
The ids are of type String. But I would like to order it according to its numerical order
Normal orderBy:'fiche.id' the list is displayed as below.
`1,10,11,12,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`

I would like the output to be of order - 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12

Comment: There is a missing id after 3. Is a part of json or typo mistake?

Comment: Show your code, make a fiddle if you can

Comment: Json is like that :   "fiche": {
   "id": "1",
   "date_creation": "2014-04-01 00:00:00",
   "date_modification": "2014-04-01 00:00:00"
  },

Comment: Show your code, make a fiddle if you can

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bcKg6/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess your ids are strings. A simple solution would be use a no. operation inside order by. So instead ofr `orderBy:'id'` just use `orderBy:'id*1'` this will consider the id as no. and sort it according to the numerical order.

This is all you need - `<div ng-repeat="fiche in fiches | orderBy:'id*1'">{{fiche.id}}</div>`

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/MSrPTZQP49F7Nzwhv6ef?p=preview

Comment: is there a way to provide a sort function with ng-repeat? I've wanted to do some more complicated sorts than by a simple attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally it should Print the correct list in ng-repeat using order-by. I am adding a fiddle example with the same.Its a basic example. Hope it helps

```
>  http://jsfiddle.net/L45cE/
```

Comment: U could print a reverse by making the orderBy:'id':true as well

Comment: it's doesn't work with my example : http://jsfiddle.net/bcKg6/ ID's always in weird order (left column)