# angular multi column orderby convers number to string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to sort on multiple columns inside angular's ng-repeat.

The 2nd column is a number, but it is being treated like a string.

Where 22 is ordered before 3

Here is a JSFiddle to reproduce the issue.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/kh6jbkgr/1/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.data = [
     {name:'Superhero', id:1},
     {name:'Superhero', id:12},
     {name:'Superhero', id:3000},
     {name:'Superhero', id:22},
     {name:'Superhero', id:7},
     {name:'Superhero', id:8},
     {name:'Superhero', id:10}
    ];
}
```

View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul>  
    <li ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy:'[name,id]'">{{item.name}} : {{item.id}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Order is..

```
Superhero : 1
Superhero : 10
Superhero : 12
Superhero : 22
Superhero : 3000
Superhero : 7
Superhero : 8
```

When it should be...

```
Superhero : 1
Superhero : 7
Superhero : 8
Superhero : 10
Superhero : 12
Superhero : 22
Superhero : 3000
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
     $scope.data = [
     {name:'Superhero', id:1},
     {name:'Superhero', id:12},
     {name:'Superhero', id:3000},
     {name:'Superhero', id:22},
     {name:'Superhero', id:7},
     {name:'Superhero', id:8},
     {name:'Superhero', id:10}
    ];
  }

]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="MainViewController.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="dobController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data| orderBy:'name':true | orderBy:'id':false" >{{item.name}} : {{item.id}}</li>
  </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: any way to do this without splitting into two statements?  I'm going to have to update a lot of code to do this work around.

Comment: if you are using angular version below 1.5.9 you can just do orderBy:['name', '1*id']

Comment: why below 1.5.9? i'm using 1.6.1

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do to achieve this is very simple.

1. Split the `orderBy` statement to two sections
2. In order to treat the id field as numeric use [1*id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029265/angularjs-ng-repeat-ordering-string-arrays-in-numerical-order) in the second statement.

Here is the working demo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy:'name' | orderBy: '1*id'">{{item.name}} : {{item.id}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        
        myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.data = [
                     {name:'Superhero', id:1},
                     {name:'Superhero', id:12},
                     {name:'Superhero', id:3000},
                     {name:'Superhero', id:22},
                     {name:'Superhero', id:7},
                     {name:'Superhero', id:8},
                     {name:'Superhero', id:10}
                    ];
        });
        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Or you can combine them in a single `orderBy` statement as `orderBy:['name', '1*id']`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in data | orderBy:['name', '1*id']">{{item.name}} : {{item.id}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        
        myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.data = [
                     {name:'Superhero', id:1},
                     {name:'Superhero', id:12},
                     {name:'Superhero', id:3000},
                     {name:'Superhero', id:22},
                     {name:'Superhero', id:7},
                     {name:'Superhero', id:8},
                     {name:'Superhero', id:10}
                    ];
        });
        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: any way to do this without splitting into two statements?  I'm going to have to update a lot of code to do this work around.

Comment: @TWilly use orderBy:['name', '1*id'] for that. I have updated that in code.